# How can I tell at what rate my battery is charging?

Tags: battery, charging, htc-evo

I've been told that different charging sources charge my phone at different rates, and have been told that some car chargers act at a normal USB rate instead of a rate closer to an AC outlet.

When I plug into my car charger, is there a way for me to see at what rate my battery is recharging?  My phone is an HTC Evo.

Comment: Related: [How can profile (log the charging and discharging current for some time period) my battery?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/115782) (Disclaimer: includes my answer there.)

Answer (score 3):

[Battery Indicator Pro](http://www.appbrain.com/app/battery-indicator-pro/com.darshancomputing.BatteryIndicatorPro) will tell you or you can go into Settings -> About -> Battery and look there.

Answer (score 1):

The [System Panel](http://android.nextapp.com/site/systempanel) app has a nice historical chart of battery usage so you can see how quickly it charges as well as how long it takes to drain.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for the actual current draw of electricity coming in to your device, the app [Ampere](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gombosdev.ampere) will display this.  Note that it may require some tweaking for certain devices.

Answer (score 0):

[CurrentWidget](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.manor.currentwidget) does the trick for me.

Comment: Which one? There's lots of battery widgets.

Comment: the one called "currentwidget" did the trick for me.

Comment: Haha, you should probably edit to clarify as "The app "Current Widget" in the market..."

Answer (score 0):

You can check the amount of current(in mA) passing to your device via some applications like:

- [Galaxy Charging Current Free](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.abmantis.galaxychargingcurrent.free)
- [Charging Report](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.playfulgeeks.chargingreport)

These apps are available for free on Google play store. They will tell you with what rate is your phone charging.

For example:-

If they show less than 500 mA then the device is charging slowly and may take a lot of time to be charged. But if it shows more than 1200 mA then that's good. For my device I get 1600mA.