# How can profile (log the charging and discharging current for some time period) my battery?

Tags: battery

As the question reads, I want to log the current in milliAmpere or Ampere (both charging and discharging) over a period of time.

Please note I am not asking about charging or discharging rate, but rather on the current. I am aware of the app called [Ampere](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gombosdev.ampere&hl=en) which displays the current, which is good but I want them logged over a period of time.  I am also aware of the app [Battery Log](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=kr.hwangti.batterylog&hl=en), which logs the details but not the current.

Device info: Nexus 5 rooted, running stock 5.1.1. Ready to install custom kernel but stock ROM only.

Edit: Based on a comment from Firelord, I could see a file in `/sys/class/power_supply/battery/current_now` which at the moment of writing had a number `835910` and after a second it became `695229`, then `673163`. All these values were during the discharge phase.

When plugged in, it showed `412190` and the Ampere app showed `160mA`.  It seems this is the current, but I guess I have to average it out to compare it with Ampere's output.

Interestingly, there is another file named `status` which has values `charging` and `discharging`.

I also happen to know [another question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/69323/where-is-the-current-now-measurement-generated) in this site.

Comment: In my Android 4.2.1, I found that this Ampere app is showing the values made available by the kernel under `/sys/class/power_supply/...`. It was easy for me to see the real value inside the file but Lollipop has made some changes so I can't find out which new file holds the value for current. Anyhow, if you do end-up with such file then use Tasker app to log the value for your time period.

Comment: Thanks @Firefox for your input. You should compile your comment as answer so that I can up vote and accept it as well.

Comment: Done posting it, and I was reluctant to post the answer but your edit about `current_now` made me to rethink about posting. :)

Comment: My bad, the auto correction features at times are just nuisance and [at times funny](http://www.damnyouautocorrect.com/).  Please read "Thanks [at]Firefox for your input" as "Thanks [at]Firelord for your input".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Ampere** shows us the value of current made available to the system by the kernel. I used three devices with different Android versions to test my answer. Here we go!

---

#### Test 1 & 2: Two MTK devices running stock Android 4.2.1 and 4.4.2

Since MTK is involved, thing would behave a bit differently. In both the devices **Ampere** had trouble measuring the current not because it couldn't, but two files were available to measure the current, and the user had to choose one from its **Settings → Basic settings → Measurement interface**. (*Rant*: A design flaw I tend to think since I wasn't aware of that before digging it up).

The two files for my Android 4.2.1:

```
/sys/device/platform/mt6320-battery/power_supply/battery/BatteryAverageCurrent
/sys/class/power_supply/battery/BatteryAverageCurrent
```

The two files for my Android 4.4.2:

```
/sys/device/platform/battery/power_supply/battery/BatteryAverageCurrent
/sys/class/power_supply/battery/BatteryAverageCurrent
```

The file `BatteryAverageCurrent` would show a numeric value with no mention of any unit (be it `A` or `mA`).

In my devices, both the files (second was the symlink of the first) had the same value (dynamic, Current varies of course) like `440` when connected to PC, and `880` when connected to charger. Correspondingly, **Ampere** showed the similar value with a slight mismatch of +- `1-10` mA.  // Somebody on XDA said that this app doesn't show true values, but that's none of my concern honestly.

#### Test 3: A Qualcomm device running Android 5.0.2 (CyanogenOS 12)

I read that Google made changes in Lollipop related to measurement of current, and among other things, `BatteryAverageCurrent` is nowhere to be found in the system, at least not in my system. Don't blame me since I didn't verify whether the changes were introduce in Lollipop or before, and it's not really a concern to test the things here.

Before I tell the tale further I should mention that **Ampere** had no trouble in this device even though there were two files to measure current:

```
/sys/devices/00-qcom,charger/power_supply/battery/current_now
/sys/class/power_supply/battery/current_now
```

Not to mention that the second one is the symlink of the first one, and `00-qcom,charger` may differ in your device.

Anyhow, when it comes to the content of the `current_now` you can consider everything same as in `BatteryAverageCurrent` except that the value was in negative like `-180` or `-840` (don't ask me why?)

#### There's more

The last directory named `battery` has some other cool stuff which might interest some people. Checkout them like Battery temperature, Voltage, capacity, among other things.

If you want a summary of them, look at `uevent` file whose output would be like:

```
POWER_SUPPLY_NAME=battery
POWER_SUPPLY_CHARGING_ENABLED=1
POWER_SUPPLY_STATUS=Charging
POWER_SUPPLY_CHARGE_TYPE=Unknown
POWER_SUPPLY_HEALTH=Good
POWER_SUPPLY_PRESENT=1
POWER_SUPPLY_ONLINE=1
POWER_SUPPLY_TECHNOLOGY=Li-ion
POWER_SUPPLY_VOLTAGE_MAX_DESIGN=4350000
POWER_SUPPLY_VOLTAGE_MIN_DESIGN=4400000
POWER_SUPPLY_VOLTAGE_NOW=4316000
POWER_SUPPLY_CAPACITY=100
POWER_SUPPLY_CURRENT_NOW=0  
POWER_SUPPLY_INPUT_CURRENT_MAX=100000
POWER_SUPPLY_INPUT_CURRENT_TRIM=33
POWER_SUPPLY_INPUT_CURRENT_SETTLED=0
POWER_SUPPLY_VOLTAGE_MIN=4300000
POWER_SUPPLY_INPUT_VOLTAGE_REGULATION=1
POWER_SUPPLY_CHARGE_FULL_DESIGN=0
POWER_SUPPLY_CHARGE_FULL=0
POWER_SUPPLY_TEMP=311
POWER_SUPPLY_TEMP_COOL=0
POWER_SUPPLY_TEMP_WARM=0
POWER_SUPPLY_SYSTEM_TEMP_LEVEL=0
POWER_SUPPLY_CYCLE_COUNT=0
POWER_SUPPLY_CHARGE_NOW=5048
POWER_SUPPLY_FASTCHARGER=0
POWER_SUPPLY_CHARGE_TIMEOUT=1
```

And if (somehow) you're wondering about `0` in `POWER_SUPPLY_CURRENT_NOW=0` then know that `POWER_SUPPLY_CAPACITY=100` i.e. charging was complete and even **Ampere** was showing `0mA`.

---

As for Logging, sorry! since I've no detailed solution as I didn't bother because the logging can be done using an automation tool like [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm).

But a brief usage of **Tasker** must be told:

- Create a profile based on time or the type that suits your goal.
- There are two file actions under the action **File** namely `Read File` and `Write File`. If it doesn't work, then you can always do `cat <SOURCE> >> <DESTINATION>` using the action **Code → Run Shell** and you don't need root access.

We're good to go now!

Answer (score 3):

This is not as in-depth as FireLord's answer, but I found a few apps that might be useful.

These all appear monitor current and have a log feature:

- **[Current Widget: Battery Monitor](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.manor.currentwidget)** by RmDroider
- **[Battery Utility Free](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.blcpk.toolkit.app)** by SUXD
- **[Advanced Battery Monitor](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=au.com.codeka.advbatterygraph)** by Codeka
- **[Battery Monitor Widget](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ccc71.bmw)** by 3c
- **[Battery Spy](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.vertiform.android.app.batteryspy)** by Vertiform Technologies

These are more general system monitors but they appear to include battery stats and logging:

- **[Elixir 2](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bartat.android.elixir)** by Tamás Barta
- **[AndroSensor](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fivasim.androsensor)** by Fiv Asim

Answer (score 1):

I tried all of the above apps, but in 2020 they all are either no longer existing or they do not log the data like we hoped.

This one does, though:

[3C Battery Monitor Widget](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ccc71.bmw)