# How to get battery status in terminal?

Tags: battery, terminal, ssh

I have a phone with dropbear installed. I usually access my phone over WiFi & run commands in putty.

I want to get battery status & percentage in terminal.  Is there any command or program  to obtain battery info ?

Comment: See if there is/are any system service(s) having the string "battery". For example, `dumpsys battery` (needs root) does the job in Android 4.2.1. Or, see if `/sys/class/power_supply/battery/BatteryAverageCurrent/uevent` give you anything. See my answer here for more: [How can profile (log the charging and discharging current for some time period) my battery?](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/116029)

Answer (score 10):

Query the system service `battery` (possibly requires root access)

```
dumpsys battery
```

Output would be like

```
Current Battery Service state:
  AC powered: false
  USB powered: true
  Wireless powered: false
  status: 2
  health: 2
  present: true
  level: 70
  scale: 100
  voltage:3950
  temperature: 260
  technology: Li-ion
```

`level: 70` is the battery percentage here.

---

Not sure about Android 2.3 but  this is relevant for at least Android 4.2.1 and above:

<sub>(Prefix *adb shell* next to every command to run the command using adb.)</sub>

- This would give you a list of all the historical broadcasts as well as the sticky ones:

  ```
  dumpsys activity broadcasts
  ```

  In the output search:

  ```
  Sticky action android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED:
  ```

  The lines next to it, until you encounter a new sticky broadcast, are useful to us. In my devices, they are listed as:

  ```
  Intent: act=android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED flg=0x60000010
  Bundle[{icon-small=17302819, present=true, scale=100, level=100, technology=Li-ion, status=4, voltage=4140, invalid_charger=0, plugged=0, health=2, temperature=200}]
  ```

  Assuming that your Android has `grep` utility, you can shorten the search by using:

  ```
  dumpsys activity broadcasts | grep -A2 "Sticky action android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED:"
  ```

  <sub>(Source: [Monitoring the Battery Level and Charging State](http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/battery-monitoring.html))</sub>
- **Alternative:** it is possible to query the battery info from `/sys`  or I should say the Linux kernel.

  `/sys/class/power_supply/battery/` has some files with useful information. The file named `capacity` is equivalent to current battery percentage. You can get an accumulated info from `uevent` file as well.

  For more and related info, read my answer [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/116029/96277).

Comment: +1 to that: I can fully confirm the first approach (via `dumpsys`), which is exactly what I successfully use with [Adebar](https://github.com/IzzySoft/Adebar), tested on multiple devices. So your command will probably be something like `dumpsys battery | grep "level:" | awk '{ print $2 }'`. However, I've never tested that with Android versions <4.

Comment: Neither did I test on <4, but posted it because OP confirmed it. :) Waiting for somebody to verify the second approach here.

Comment: Looks like I can confirm this for `cat /sys/class/power_supply/battery/capacity` at least on Android 4.1. As sysfs is a Linux feature already available for quite a while, this should work on other/previous Android versions as well. Other "files" in the context of the question: `health` (e.g. "Good"), `status` ("Full"), `temp` (centi-degrees Celsius? here: "300"). Just figuring the current power source might prove a bit tricky :)

Comment: still works! `cat /sys/class/power_supply/battery/status` cool thanks

Answer (score 1):

#### Script to show battery status on terminal (root required)

Using only the alternative method @Firelord mentioned.

```
#!/system/bin/sh # might need to change to your sh bin 

print_battery_status()
{
    ctype=`cat /sys/class/power_supply/battery/charge_type`
    capacity=`cat /sys/class/power_supply/battery/capacity`
    charging=`cat /sys/class/power_supply/battery/charging_enabled`
    health=`cat /sys/class/power_supply/battery/health`
    status=`cat /sys/class/power_supply/battery/status`
    printf "# %s # %s # %s # %s # %s #\r" "Capacity: ${capacity}" "Charging: ${charging}" "Type: ${ctype}" "Health: ${health}" "Status: ${status}"
}

while [ true ]
do
    print_battery_status
    sleep 1 # 1 second of wait
done
```

You might need to adapt the script a bit. Some file names used above are device specific. For example, `charging_enable` should be replaced by `charge_now` and some devices, and so on.

It runs and shows status like bellow. To stop it use CRTL+C.

```
./batery_status.sh
# Capacity: 63 # Charging: 1 # Type: Fast # Health: Good # Status: Charging #
```

I use this since I do remote ssh on my device. It works even with zygote stopped.