# How to automate sending my current battery percentage to PC over the internet every 5 minutes?

Tags: battery-life, automation, terminal, scripts

I'm using **`Android 9`** on my device, there are many times when I'm away from my phone and it is charging in a different room or someone else is using it, is there was a way to send over the battery percentage say **bp** over to my PC at regular intervals via the internet.

There maybe apps that can do this but I'm interested more in a script *or* terminal based approach

Ideas I'm thinking of are:

- using a **script manager** on my phone like https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.androidideas.scriptlauncher
- **`crontab`** with a script that sends out bp to a copy pasta and my PC can have it's own script reading that
- using `cat /sys/class/power_supply/battery/capacity` or `dumpsys battery | grep "level:" | awk '{ print $2 }'` once my device is **rooted** as mentioned here : [How to get battery status in terminal?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/128015/how-to-get-battery-status-in-terminal) and doing that every **N** minutes using `cron`

I have `Termux` installed and my device is not rooted yet how do I proceed.

Comment: Usually your PC is not exposed to the Internet, therefore a (temporary) storage is needed online. Typical examples are storage services like Dropbox, document services like Google Sheets or messaging systems like Signal or Wire. I am sure for a lot of services termux/Linux scripts exist that allow to store data in one of these services.

Comment: @Robert Exactly why I was thinking of a copy pasta aka a pastebin service to broadcast my battery status to for example maybe ix.io but I'm sure the people here have something even simpler. Another issue is how I'm going to get the battery percentage in terminal without rooting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using **`gist`** by Github (which can be done using `gem install gist` after installing `ruby` package) for broadcasting my battery percentage first to a private file,  tried using **`ix.io`** but `pkg install ix` didn't work on Android terminal the `config.guess` threw and error saying `unable to guess system type`.

Already had **`Termux`** installed on my Android with necessary packages and with **`pkg install termux-battery-status`** and installing the Playstore api app : https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.termux.api&hl=en_IN using `termux-battery-status | grep percentage | grep -oP '\: (.*?)\,' | grep -Eo '[0-9]{1,3}'` gave the battery percentage in terminal.

Finally I added permissions using `chmod +x bp.sh` and set up **`crontab`** on Android to do this every minute using `crontab -e` and adding the line `* * * * * ~/bp.sh`

**EDIT**

Have started to make use of `jq` to parse `json` ouput, so now the one liner for script is `termux-battery-status | jq .percentage | gist -f bp -u gist_id` and start the crontab using `crond`

PS : I've put the entire thing here :  https://github.com/himanshuxd/bp-broadcast

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Your Phone Companion](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.microsoft.appmanager) from Microsoft to link Android to your PC. The battery percentage would be shown at the upper left corner near device icon.

Comment: It won't work when I'm using `Ubuntu` or `Arch` plus the permission list for that app is quite taxing.

Comment: You could try Find My Device which requires GPS to be active.